# Can't access all administration pages in Frontpage Server Extensions

Tags: web-server

I have an old FrontPage box running Windows 2003 server and IIS6 and I can't get to the administration page I'm looking for.

I can get to _vti_bin/_vti_adm/fpadmdll.dll?page=webadmin.htm and change settings there. I can also get to other pages that are linked from here, to do things like create subwebs, version control, check server health, and manage users and roles.

But it looks like what I have to get to is fpadmin.htm, which then has a link to "Set Installation Defaults", which appears to be policies.htm.

Problem is if I change ?page= to be any of these, it just says "The webpage cannot be found"

I can see the html files for the pages I need are in:
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\50\admisapi\1033